# use ko.utils.arrayfilter to return collection based on value of inner collection

Tags: json, knockout.js

I am using knockout and want to use arrayFilter to return array of objects where a property "modified" inside of another array has value of true.

i.e.
my json object looks like

```
Family tree
Family{
  LastName=Smith
  Children{
    Name=bob,
    Modified=false},
   {
    Name=tom, Modified=true}
 }
Family{
  LastName=Jones
  Children{
    Name=bruno,
    Modified=false},
   {
    Name=mary, Modified=false}
 }
```

The result of the array filter would be (as follows) becuase child tom has modified =true

```
FamilyTree
  Family{
  LastName=Smith
  Children{
    Name=bob,
    Modified=false},
   {
    Name=tom, Modified=true}
 }
```

is this possible?

Comment: So you want your filter list to contain any `Family` where *at least one* child has `Modified = true`? Yes of course it's possible. What have you tried? Where are you having problems?

Comment: Yes, yes it is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the solution that @pax162 supplied probably answers your question. However, there is the question of usage. The proposed solution is going to perform nested iterations. If you are only expecting to be processing the data once (as opposed to driving some rich client views), this is the approach to take. On the other hand, if you are binding this data to a view, you might consider another more KO-like approach. Here's what I have in mind:

```
var family = function(data){
    var self = {
        LastName :ko.observable(data.LastName),
        Children : ko.observableArray( data.Children || [])
    };

    family.hasModifiedChildren = ko.computed(function() {
        return ko.utils.arrayFirst(this.Children(), 
            function(child) {
                return child.Modified === true;
            }) !== null;
    }, family);

    return self;
}
```

Rather than using JSON data, create observable JS objects as such:

```
var families = return ko.utils.arrayMap(familiesJson, family);
// or, if you need an observable:
families = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(familiesJson, family));
```

Finally, get your list of families with modified children like this:

```
var familiesWithModifiedChildren = ko.computed(function() { 
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(families, function(fam) {
        return fam.hasModifiedChildren();
    });
});
```

If you are building a live-update page, you'll want to go with this style of view model. This will allow Knockout to utilize its observer optimizations rather than building a new array every time the function is evaluated. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get only families with at least one modified child, you can do this (http://jsfiddle.net/MAyNn/3/) . The json was not valid, changed it a bit.

```
 var families = [
{
    LastName :"Smith",
    Children : [{
    Name:"bob",
    Modified:false},
   {
       Name:"tom", Modified :true}
 ]
},
{
    LastName :"Jones",
    Children : [{
    Name:"bruno",
    Modified:false},
   {
       Name:"mary", Modified :false}
 ]
}   
 ];

var filteredFamilies = ko.utils.arrayFilter(families, function(family){
    var hasModified = false;
    var first = ko.utils.arrayFirst(family.Children, function(child){
        return child.Modified;
    })
    if (first) {
        hasModified = true;
    }

    return hasModified;
})

console.log(families);
console.log(filteredFamilies);
```

Comment: One note about this function: when iterating over the Children node, use arrayFirst to find the first instance of a modified child. This will save you some needless cycles.

Comment: This works very nice, how can I modify to return, only those child elements that changed? ty

FamilyTree
  Family{
  LastName=Smith
  Children{ 
    Name=tom, Modified=true}
 }